# Unable to resolve service for type in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, controller

I get this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type

I am using are unit of work repository project, on .NET Core. I had a services on another layer, but I changed to TestServices, then I created a Services layer where are `FlightService` and `IFlightService`.

Program

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IFlightRepository, FlightRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

`FlightController`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Api")]
public class FlightController : Controller
{
        private readonly ILogger<SearchFlightsController> _logger;        
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public readonly IFlightService _flightService;

        public FlightController(ILogger<SearchFlightsController> logger,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            IFlightService flightService)
        {
            _logger = logger;            
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _flightService = flightService;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetFlightById/{flightId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFlightById(int flightId)
        {
            var details = await _flightService.GetFlightById(flightId);

            if (details != null)
            {
                return Ok(details);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
}
```

Error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Services.Interfaces.IFlightService' while attempting to activate 'NewShore.Controllers.FlightController'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method4(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I read some posts, I tried changing to `AddScoped` both, `AddTransient` for `IFlightRepository`. I saw the order or the commands on `Program.cs` but everything seems ok.

Can you please correct me?

Comment: Please post the error message including Stacktrace.

Comment: Error information added.

Comment: You add `IFlightRepository` but not `IFlightService` that is used in your controller. And that's what the error is telling you : the app doesn't know about `IFlightService` that you want to use in your controller, as you didn't add the service in your startup

EDIT : @riktus was faster than me :). Check his answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You injected IFlightService into FlightController, but not registered this dependency. Error message tells you that dependency in FlightController cannot be resolved.

Add this line to Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IFlightService, FligtService>();
```

Comment: FightService and FlightRepository... they look similar, thanks guys.